# C# object compare and memory allocation

Tags: c#

My coworker has 10 `CopyIfDifferent` functions for most of the primitive types. `string`, `int`, `double`, `bool`...

I did a test with 10 million items and on my machine changing the value was around 40% faster than checking if they are different and then changing them. I tested both for 10 million items that did not need to be changed and 10 million items that needed to be changed.

When asking him why he has these function instead of just changing the values given that it's cheaper. He told me that it was to prevent memory allocation and memory fragmentation. So if the object is the same it can stay in the same memory address and therefore be faster.

```
public static void CopyIfDifferent(ref string vValueToCopyTo, string vValueToCopyFrom)
{
    if (!ValuesAreEqual(vValueToCopyTo, vValueToCopyFrom))
    {
        vValueToCopyTo = vValueToCopyFrom;
    }
}
public static bool ValuesAreEqual(string vValue1, string vValue2)
{
    if (vValue1 == null && vValue2 == null)
    {
        return true;
    }
    if (vValue1 == null || vValue2 == null)
    {
        return false;
    }
    return vValue1 == vValue2;
}
```

Using the function

```
Utils.CopyIfDifferent(ref GroupIDFK, item.GroupIDFK);
```

My Question is. Is it better to check the value before changing it rather than just change? If so why?

Comment: How about `Interlocked.CompareExchange(...)`? :) There is also a generic version.

Comment: With `string` being a reference type, the instances "stay in the same address" anyway; the data is not really copied. Also, why is the `ValuesAreEqual` method so verbose; why not use *only* the last line (`return vValue1 == vValue2`)?

Comment: Your coworker does not understand the .NET memory model. Delete those useless functions.

Comment: It is a brave attempt and shining example of sad tragedy of micro-optimization - and in this case it doesn't even work :)

Comment: Tell your coworker that if he's trying to solve a problem, he should identify the problem first (i.e., benchmarking and spotting the bottleneck). *If* there is a problem, then you should prove that your solution works (i.e., the bottleneck has moved somewhere else). It seems he had done neither.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just looking at the string function, if anything this is going to INCREASE memory usage, not decrease it. (However, because of string interning it normally won't actually increase memory usage much, but it won't help either.)

Why? Well, let's look at the method:

```
public static void CopyIfDifferent(ref string vValueToCopyTo, string vValueToCopyFrom)
{
    if (!ValuesAreEqual(vValueToCopyTo, vValueToCopyFrom))
    {
        vValueToCopyTo = vValueToCopyFrom;
    }
}
```

Now consider calling it when the strings are different:

```
string s1 = "One";
string s2 = "Two";

CopyIfDifferent(ref s2, s1);
```

What will this do? Well, it will do exactly the same as doing:

```
s2 = s1;
```

only with the overhead of a method call and an expensive string compare. So that's pointless.

Now how about if the strings are the same? In this case, it will do nothing, and will leave `s2` with it's original reference. This means that we now have two references to a string with the same contents instead of one - which is ostensibly a waste of memory and makes things worse. Fortunately, because of string interning only one actual copy of the string will (normally) be held in memory, which mitigates the problem slightly.

So overall this is a complete waste of time, it makes things slower, and you should certainly not do it.

And what of doing this with value types such as `int`? If the implementation looks like this:

```
public static void CopyIfDifferent(ref int vValueToCopyTo, int vValueToCopyFrom)
{
    if (!ValuesAreEqual(vValueToCopyTo, vValueToCopyFrom))
    {
        vValueToCopyTo = vValueToCopyFrom;
    }
}

public static bool ValuesAreEqual(int vValue1, int vValue2)
{
    return vValue1 == vValue2;
}
```

it would be just awful...

A simple `int x = y;` gets turned into a horribly inefficient pushing of a pointer onto the stack (the `ref` param) followed by dereferencing the pointer (when comparing the values) and then assigning to the pointer if the values are different.

And like @dcastro points out below, the `int` is being copied 3 times anyway - which makes a complete mockery of trying to optimise out the copying of an `int` in the first place.

Just... no. A thousand times, no.

Comment: Plus, in your last example, the `int` value was copied three times (2 method calls + 1 assignment) instead of just once.

Answer (score 3):

Regarding prevent memory allocation and memory fragmentation it is useless for value type because there are no change in reference  The variable has its own memory and its content is replaced so there are no new memory allocation.

IMHO  the only reason to check for equality before set a value type are:

- you need to raise some events (like OnChange)
- setting that value will start a complex action like saving it on a database or refresh the cache
- that value type is really frequently setted.

A simple test can show how  performs:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Process proc = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
            Console.WriteLine("GetTotalMemory:{0} PrivateMemorySize64:{1}  press enter to continue", GC.GetTotalMemory(true), proc.PrivateMemorySize64);
            Console.ReadLine();

            const int testCount = 1000000000;
            var stopWatch = new Stopwatch();

            int a = 2456;
            int b = 2456;
            stopWatch.Start();
            for (int i = 0; i < testCount; i++)
            {
                CopyIfDifferent(ref a, b);
            }
            stopWatch.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("int equal CopyIfDifferent ElapsedMilliseconds:{0}", stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
            Console.WriteLine("GetTotalMemory:{0} PrivateMemorySize64:{1}  press enter to continue", GC.GetTotalMemory(true), proc.PrivateMemorySize64);
            GC.Collect();
            Console.ReadLine();
            stopWatch.Restart();
            for (int i = 0; i < testCount; i++)
            {
                a = b;
            }
            stopWatch.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("int equal assignment ElapsedMilliseconds:{0}", stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
            Console.WriteLine("GetTotalMemory:{0} PrivateMemorySize64:{1}  press enter to continue", GC.GetTotalMemory(true), proc.PrivateMemorySize64);
            Console.ReadLine();
            string c = "dfsgdgdfg";
            string d = "dfsgdgdfg";
            stopWatch.Restart();
            for (int i = 0; i < testCount; i++)
            {
                CopyIfDifferent(ref c, d);
            }
            stopWatch.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("string equal CopyIfDifferent ElapsedMilliseconds:{0}", stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
            Console.WriteLine("GetTotalMemory:{0} PrivateMemorySize64:{1}  press enter to continue", GC.GetTotalMemory(true), proc.PrivateMemorySize64);
            Console.ReadLine();
            stopWatch.Restart();
            for (int i = 0; i < testCount; i++)
            {
                c = d;
            }
            stopWatch.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("string equal assignment ElapsedMilliseconds:{0}", stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
            Console.WriteLine("GetTotalMemory:{0} PrivateMemorySize64:{1}  press enter to continue", GC.GetTotalMemory(true), proc.PrivateMemorySize64);
            Console.ReadLine();
            int e = 2456;
            int f = 3465464;
            stopWatch.Restart();
            for (int i = 0; i < testCount; i++)
            {
                CopyIfDifferent(ref e, f);
            }
            stopWatch.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("int different CopyIfDifferent ElapsedMilliseconds:{0}", stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
            Console.WriteLine("GetTotalMemory:{0} PrivateMemorySize64:{1}  press enter to continue", GC.GetTotalMemory(true), proc.PrivateMemorySize64);
            Console.ReadLine();
            stopWatch.Restart();
            for (int i = 0; i < testCount; i++)
            {
                e = f;
            }
            stopWatch.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("int different assignment ElapsedMilliseconds:{0}", stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
            Console.WriteLine("GetTotalMemory:{0} PrivateMemorySize64:{1}  press enter to continue", GC.GetTotalMemory(true), proc.PrivateMemorySize64);
            Console.ReadLine();
            string g = "dfsgdgdfg";
            string h = "gdfhfghfghfghf";
            stopWatch.Restart();
            for (int i = 0; i < testCount; i++)
            {
                CopyIfDifferent(ref g, h);
            }
            stopWatch.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("string different CopyIfDifferent ElapsedMilliseconds:{0}", stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
            Console.WriteLine("GetTotalMemory:{0} PrivateMemorySize64:{1}  press enter to continue", GC.GetTotalMemory(true), proc.PrivateMemorySize64);
            Console.ReadLine();
            stopWatch.Restart();
            for (int i = 0; i < testCount; i++)
            {
                g = h;
            }
            stopWatch.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("string different assignment ElapsedMilliseconds:{0}", stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
            Console.WriteLine("GetTotalMemory:{0} PrivateMemorySize64:{1}  press enter to continue", GC.GetTotalMemory(true), proc.PrivateMemorySize64);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        public static void CopyIfDifferent(ref string vValueToCopyTo, string vValueToCopyFrom)
        {
            if (!ValuesAreEqual(vValueToCopyTo, vValueToCopyFrom))
            {
                vValueToCopyTo = vValueToCopyFrom;
            }
        }
        public static void CopyIfDifferent(ref int vValueToCopyTo, int vValueToCopyFrom)
        {
            if (vValueToCopyTo != vValueToCopyFrom)
            {
                vValueToCopyTo = vValueToCopyFrom;
            }
        }
        public static bool ValuesAreEqual(string vValue1, string vValue2)
        {
            if (vValue1 == null && vValue2 == null)
            {
                return true;
            }
            if (vValue1 == null || vValue2 == null)
            {
                return false;
            }
            return vValue1 == vValue2;
        }
    }
}
```

Results:

> GetTotalMemory:22764 PrivateMemorySize64:6815744
>
> int equal CopyIfDifferent ElapsedMilliseconds:1078
>   GetTotalMemory:36608 PrivateMemorySize64:6815744
>
> int equal assignment ElapsedMilliseconds:540 GetTotalMemory:36608
>   PrivateMemorySize64:6815744
>
> string equal CopyIfDifferent ElapsedMilliseconds:10782
>   GetTotalMemory:36608 PrivateMemorySize64:6815744
>
> string equal assignment ElapsedMilliseconds:1077 GetTotalMemory:36608
>   PrivateMemorySize64:6815744
>
> int different CopyIfDifferent ElapsedMilliseconds:1078
>   GetTotalMemory:36608 PrivateMemorySize64:6815744
>
> int different assignment ElapsedMilliseconds:540 GetTotalMemory:36608
>   PrivateMemorySize64:6815744
>
> string different CopyIfDifferent ElapsedMilliseconds:10241
>   GetTotalMemory:36608 PrivateMemorySize64:6815744
>
> string different assignment ElapsedMilliseconds:1076
>   GetTotalMemory:36608 PrivateMemorySize64:6815744

Also Resharper tells you that it is useless for value type

[image]

Comment: "all the value type use the same memory address" - what do you mean by this? Are you saying that they're interned? I.e., `int x = 1; int y = 1;`, and `x` and `y` will be stored in the same address?

Comment: @dcastro absolutely no! what I mean is that there are no change in reference . the variable has its own memory and its content is replaced so there are no new memory allocation.

Comment: Correct ;) Can you please edit your answer to explain that bit better then?

Comment: @dcastro done, thanks for making me note that I was not clear!

Answer (score 2):

It's *useless*, since when you copy string it's *reference changing* (which is 4 or 8 bytes long) at most. There's *another isssue* with the `String` class: there're *standard alogorithms* to compare Strings and that's why we should not *re-invent the wheel*:

```
// Compare strings: case sensitive, current culture 
if (String.Equals(vValueToCopyTo, vValueToCopyFrom))
  vValueToCopyTo = vValueToCopyFrom;

// Compare strings: case insensitive and invariant culture 
if (String.Equals(vValueToCopyTo, vValueToCopyFrom, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
  vValueToCopyTo = vValueToCopyFrom;
```

As for *struct*, e.g. `int`, it's even harmful: standard comparison

```
  if (a == b)
    a = b;
```

will be *eliminated* by optimizer (if `a == b` there's no need to assign `a = b;`) at all, and so it'll cost you *nothing*; when a little bit different comparison is compiling

```
  if (a != b) // != instead of ==
    a = b;
```

it has a good chance to be translated into *3 assembly commands* (`XOR, JZ, MOV`) only; on the contrary, a *special function call* means *argument coping*, additional `SUB` and `RET` assembler commands, reflection information etc.

Comment: What about for example int?

Comment: @BjarkiHeiðar Integers are just integers. There are no pointers, no references, no allocations, no memory fragmentation. Like I said above, just delete those useless functions. And if you don't believe us, your benchmark shows we are correct, and testing your program will show that a simple assignment is equally correct.

Comment: @Bjarki Heiðar: As for int, the special function is even harmful, not just ineffective

Answer (score 0):

Yes, my guess it is the most efficient is to swap pointers (just change) than to check for differences because checking will take more time.

Even in case of the fastest check, which is checking for reference equality, the reference swapping will take (more or less) the same amount of time.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another angle:

For strings there may be a case to do this. (For the others there is no point)

At the point of the operation, we already have two strings allocated in the heap (I'm talking about the strings themselves not the references)  And after the operation, most probably, one of these strings will not have a live object pointing to it and will be garbage collected. So if the two strings at the heap are the same, keeping the one that has been allocated earlier would create less work for GC.

Does this make it worth checking every string? Probably not for most of the cases but there might be a corner case based on the number of strings, frequency of non-real updates, etc.